# Can my host OS see my VM's VPN traffic?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn

Example:

I have a work machine which I run a Linux VM using VMWare Workstation 9.  I have a VPN client installed on the VM.

If I connect to the VPN on the virtual machine, can the host OS see any of that traffic unencrypted?

I'm using NAT for networking.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't.  The linux kernel treats the VPN tunnel as a network device, so your traffic goes from your application to the VPN tunnel device, which encrypts it, and then sends the encrypted traffic through the VM's emulated network device, which VMWare sends out through the real physical network device. But it should be encrypted before it leaves your VM, just like it would on a real machine. Your Linux VM won't know the difference.

Comment: Good answer, but you should mention the possibility of a man in the middle attack.